# How to fix css grid-rows that are not spanning correctly?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have content that won't span 2 rows unless I give it a position: absolute for some reason, but then it overlaps the footer on pages with longer content. This is an example on the site I'm working on: https://carlisleacademymaine.com/pony-club-riding-center-program/

When I test it on the simple code below it seems to work fine, but on my site it doesn't. Maybe something else on the site is causing problems, but I can't figure it out.

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 400px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 40px minmax(760px, auto) auto auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    grid-gap: 0;
    position: relative;
    grid-template-areas: none;  
}
.header {
    background-color: aqua;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;   
}
.main-content {
    background-color: chartreuse;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start:  2; 
    grid-row-end: 4;
}
.sidebar-widget {
    background-color: lightblue;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.footer {
    background-color: aqua;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row:   4 / 5; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div> 
    <div class="main-content">content </div>
    <div class="sidebar-widget">extras</div> 
    <div class="footer">This is my foot</div>        

</div>
```

Comment: I can't figure out the exact solution but I know it's related to the your grid-template-rows, if you change it to ```grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 200px);``` you will see the correct alignment except that the footer and header are much taller than you want.

Comment: Does your project implement the following declaration: `* {box-sizing: border box;}`? If not, give that a spin~

Comment: Yep, I am using box-sizing.

Comment: You say you have a `.main-content` div inside `.container`, but on your website you have `.container > main > .main-content`. Change `.main-content` to `main` on your CSS or fix your HTML.

Comment: @arieljuod That was it! Thank you!!!